# how can i display contact us page on front page drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I am creating scratch theme in drupal 8. Problem is occurred now i want to show `contact us` block display front page in footer right corner. I had used contact form module but it opens new page. I also used Contact block but result is nothing my concern is that how to does this?

If any one knows, tell me i do not have more knowledge about drupal thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print render($block['content']);
```

Comment: thanks vinod sir ,here is my page--front.html.twig write this code in it ?

Comment: i find more about  module_invoke then get the result it used in drupal 7 if i want use drupal 8 it possiable

Comment: does any one can tell me how to use module_invoke drupal 8 thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You define a path to your form **admin/content/webform**.
Then you define your home page in Site Information **admin/config/system/site-information**.

Comment: thanks denish. but still i find other solution.does it possible using codding ?.i have use contact module now

Comment: Why do you want to code? Other solution is to create a panel, and add your block into it, then define this panel has home page. Panel should give you enough flexibility to do what you want. Coding to add a block into a page is almost never best practices.

Comment: Thanks impalement it

Answer (score 0):

More easy, contact block + twig tweak module, get the frontpage node theme sugestion, in my case node 2, -> node--2--full.html.twig and theming it.
content.field_my_field for fields and
drupal_block('mymachinenamebock') -> drupal_block('contactblock') got by the twig tweaks module

Answer (score 0):

You can include the contact form to the footer region by modifying your theme's your_theme_name.theme file.

Comment: This is more of a comment than answer. The fact that you don't have enough reputation to share comments does not entitle you to write comments as answers.